# How to put data in JTable from Vector with java

Tags: java, swing, object, vector, jtable

I have a table which has only field names and no data, I want to enter data from inputs 
by Vector

i try this cod but is't work

```
 Object[][] ss= new frand[1][];
      for(int i = 0 ; i<feeds.size();i++){
          ss[1][i]=feeds.get(i);

      }
    JTable table = new JTable(
//      new Object[][] {
//        new frand[] { feeds.get(0) },
//        new frand[] { feeds.get(1) }
//      },
            ss,
      new String[] { "connect client " }
    );
  frandtabmodule module =  new frandtabmodule(feeds);
    table.setModel(module);
```

how do I do that?

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Pay special attention to the table model section, you need to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

to load the table from an array A, if the table just create it, you can simply use:

```
     table.setModel (new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel (
                 new String [] [] {
 {"2014-02-22", A.get(0)}
     }   ,          
                 new String [] {
             "Date", "Total" 
         }));
```

if not, you can use the DefaultTableModel class and its methods and AddColumn addRow

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you first create a table by passing data and columns, then create a model and set the model. When you pass column and row data in `JTable` constructor, then the table creates and uses `DefaultTableModel` that is initialized with that data. If you have a specialized model `frandtabmodule` that wraps around the original vector `feeds` there is no need to build an array and pass it to the table. Just use `JTable` default constructor and then call `setModel`, or use a constructor that takes a model as an argument.

See [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details and examples.

EDIT:

Not sure is that is the intention, but the posted code indicates that you want to use the vector elements as columns. If that is not the intention, then it seems you have a mix up of indexes while building an array. The first set of square brackets is for the rows and the second is for columns. For example:

```
private static Object[][] vector2DArray(Vector<Object> sourceVector) {
    Object[][] rows = new Object[sourceVector.size()][1];

    for (int i = 0; i < sourceVector.size(); i++) {
        rows[i][0] = sourceVector.get(i);
    }

    return rows;
}
```